# replace several line regexp function in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql

Is there any way to delete several lines from a string?
I have a varchar value with a large amount of strings in it:

```
declare
  v_txt varchar(4000);
  v_txt2 varchar(4000);
begin
  v_txt := '<Html>
          <Head>
          <meta charset="windows-1251" />
          <style>
             div {text-indent: 40px;}
          </style>
          <style>
             p {text-indent: 40px;}
          </style>
          </Head>
          <Body>
          <font face="Arial">'

  select regexp_replace(v_txt, some_pattern, '') into v_txt2 from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_txt2);
end;
```

I need lines situated between the first 'style' tag and the last '/style' tag to be deleted?
How can i implement it? With what "some_pattern"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use REGEXP:

```
with t(val) as(
  select '<Html>
          <Head>
          <meta charset="windows-1251" />
          <style>
             div {text-indent: 40px;}
          </style>
          <style>
             p {text-indent: 40px;}
          </style>
          </Head>
          <Body>
          <font face="Arial">' from dual 
)
select substr(val, instr(val, '<style>'), instr(val, '</style>', -1, 1) - instr(val, '<style>', 1, 1) + length('</style>')) val
  from t

                                      VAL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<style> div {text-indent: 40px;} </style> <style> p {text-indent: 40px;} </style>
```

Comment: You gave me a nice idea. Thanks a lot. I've achieved what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with regexp:

```
select regexp_replace(v_txt, '<style>.*</style>', '[REPLACED]', 1, 1, 'n') into v_txt2 from dual;
```

Result is:

```
<Html>
          <Head>
          <meta charset="windows-1251" />
          [REPLACED]
          </Head>
          <Body>
          <font face="Arial">
```